# How to efficiently implement variable filter conditions in an R data.table?

Tags: r, filter, data.table

I have a large R data.table DT with many columns, for which I want to execute variable filter conditions (can be 20 or more conditions).
Single filter conditions might be absent or provided (e.g. by a shiny input). There might be also the need to combine filter inputs using "%between%" statements or conditions that cover two columns such as " | (C2 >=30 & C3 <= 44)".
The bottom line is: how can I efficiently pass variable filter conditions to the data.table search? I am looking for a flexible and fast solution und it feels that eval(parse()) might not be the best way to go here.

A simple example:

```
  library(data.table)
  library(microbenchmark)
  
  DT <- data.table(C_id = 1:26, C1=rep(LETTERS[1:26]), C2=11:36, C3=21:46)
  
  C1ids = c("A", "B", "C")
  C2ids = 1:30
  C3ids = 21:30
  
  my_filter <- function(DT, C1_ids=NULL, C2_ids=NULL, C3_ids = NULL) {
    
    x <- "C_id>0"
    if(!is.null(C1_ids)){x <- paste0(x, " & C1 %in% C1_ids")}
    if(!is.null(C2_ids)){x <- paste0(x, " & C2 %in% C2_ids")}
    if(!is.null(C2_ids)){x <- paste0(x, " & C3 %in% C3_ids")}
    
    DT <- DT[eval(parse(text=x)),]
    return(DT)
  }
  
  my_filter(DT, C1_ids = C1ids, C2_ids = C2ids, C3_ids = C3ids)
  DT[C_id>0 & C1 %in% C1ids & C2 %in% C2ids & C3 %in% C3ids]
  
  microbenchmark(my_filter(DT, C1_ids = C1ids, C2_ids = C2ids, C3_ids = C3ids))
  microbenchmark(DT[C_id>0 & C1 %in% C1ids & C2 %in% C2ids & C3 %in% C3ids])
```

Comment: If you have a large data.table, why are you benchmarking with a tiny data.table? Your solution is fine as you will see if you change to `DT <- data.table(C_id = rep(1:26, 1e5), ...`. Also, change your benchmark code to `microbenchmark(my_filter = my_filter(DT, C1_ids = C1ids, C2_ids = C2ids, C3_ids = C3ids), data.table = DT[C_id>0 & C1 %in% C1ids & C2 %in% C2ids & C3 %in% C3ids])`.

Comment: However, you should ensure in your shiny app that the user can't pass arbitrary code. Limit then to a few functions such as `==`, `!=`, ... .